# Pointer points to wrong direction after reallocating memory

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, realloc

After calling `addBakeType()` first time it it properly adds new BakeType object pointer to array, but after calling it for second time it seems to change adress of array during `realloc()` so pointers that point to previous element in array are getting messed up and point to wrong memory. Any ideas how to handle it?

```
typedef struct BakeryType {
    char *name;
} BakeType;

BakeType *bakeTypeList=NULL;
int baketypelistcounter=0;


BakeType* addBakeType(char *str){
    baketypelistcounter++;
    bakeTypeList = realloc(bakeTypeList, baketypelistcounter * sizeof (BakeType));
    BakeType *newBakeType = bakeTypeList + baketypelistcounter - 1;
    newBakeType->name=malloc(10* sizeof(char));

    newBakeType->name=str;
    return newBakeType;
}
```

Comment: You can't. Use an index number as reference, relative to the start of the array instead of a pointer.

Comment: you need to strdup the string when you store it your structure, or strcpy it when you manually allocate memory for it (as you did, although you should allocate the right amount of memory according to the string length, instead of a fixed number of 10 bytes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it like that. When you realloc and make the memory block larger, the memory block may need to be moved if there is another memory block behind it, preventing it from growing.

Your options to avoid this are:

1. `malloc()` each BakeType separately. So instead of the list being of actual BakeTypes, it will be of pointers-to-BakeType. Then only the array holding the pointers will be moved. Note that there is an overhead to a `malloc()`ed block. So if your BakeType really is just a `char*`, just get rid of `BakeType` and return the `char*` directly. If you expect more fields, it's probably fine.
2. Instead of returning a `BakeType*`, return `baketypelistcounter -1`, i.e. the index, and use `bakeTypeList[theIndex]` instead to get a pointer when you actually need it. This of course only works if you only expect to add to the list and never remove, because if you remove a lower index, all higher ones will change.

And as others have mentioned, your assignment to name is wrong. It `malloc()`s 10 bytes, then overwrites the pointer with the address of the string constant. A correct version of your code would be:

```
int strByteCount = strlen(str) + 1;
newBakeType->name = malloc(strByteCount * sizeof(char));
memcpy(newBakeType->name, str, strByteCount);
```

Or shorter

```
newBakeType->name = strdup(str);
```

as strings in C are just `malloc()`ed memory blocks, so your variable contains only the address of the memory block. So assigning one string to the other does not copy one string to the other, but rather just references the other string.

Answer (score 1):

These statements

```
newBakeType->name=malloc(10* sizeof(char));

newBakeType->name=str;
```

result in a memory leak.

At first the pointer `newBakeType->name` points to the allocated memory and then it is overwritten by the value of the pointer str.

You should use either the standard C function strcpy or strncpy as for example

```
strcpy( newBakeType->name, str );
```

But before this call you have to allocate memory of a correct size like

```
newBakeType->name = malloc( strlen( str ) + 1 );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct BakeryType {
    char *name;
} BakeType;

BakeType *bakeTypeList=NULL;
int baketypelistcounter=0;


BakeType* addBakeType( const char *str ){
    BakeType *newBakeType = NULL;

    BakeType *tmp = realloc(bakeTypeList, ( baketypelistcounter + 1 ) * sizeof (BakeType));

    if ( tmp != NULL )
    {
        baketypelistcounter++;
        bakeTypeList = tmp;

        newBakeType = bakeTypeList + baketypelistcounter - 1;

        newBakeType->name=malloc( strlen( str ) + 1 );

        if ( newBakeType->name != NULL )
        {
            strcpy( newBakeType->name, str );
        }

    }

    return newBakeType;
}

int main(void) 
{
    BakeType  *lastBakeType =  addBakeType( "A" );

    puts( lastBakeType->name );

    lastBakeType =  addBakeType( "B" );

    puts( lastBakeType->name );

    for ( const BakeType *current = bakeTypeList; 
          current != bakeTypeList + baketypelistcounter;
          ++current )
    {
        puts( current->name );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
A
B
A
B
```